# is tornado is the same as django?

Tags: django

is tornado is the same as django ?
 **can I upload tornado project to normal host providers**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Tornado is a full web server. Django is a web framework that happens to have a web server included that can be used for testing. You will need more than just basic shared hosting to run it, preferably a full VPS.

Comment: sorry my English is weak , I understood that tornado project files  can be uploaded in any hosting providers and worked properly. is  it yes ?

Comment: Tornado does not have "project files". Tornado is a whole *web server*, in the same manner as httpd or nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will find this article interesting. Note that you cannot really compare Django to Tornado. Like @Ignacio said above they are not the same thing.

The article:
http://5cience.net/blog/tornado-vs-django,4258/

And yes if you can upload tornado project to normal host providers.